# Como tratar no C# dados vindo de uma tabela que é do tipo bit no sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

No visual Studio ficará assim:

```
alerta.DataHoraCadastro = dr.Get(12);
```

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No caso você terá que converter a informação para boolean.
Ficaria assim:

```
alerta.DataHoraCadastro = dr.GetBoolean(12);
```

Comment: Funcionou meu chapa.